# What are the different methods to destroy a projected image?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The spell [**Project Image**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/project-image/), lets you create an illusion of yourself that can throw spells :

> ### Project Image
>
> You tap energy from the Plane of Shadow to create a quasi-real,
>   illusory version of yourself. The projected image looks, sounds, and
>   smells like you but is intangible. The projected image mimics your
>   actions (including speech) unless you direct it to act differently
>   (which is a move action).
>
> You can see through its eyes and hear through its ears as if you were
>   standing where it is, and during your turn you can switch from using
>   its senses to using your own, or back again, as a free action. While
>   you are using its senses, your body is considered blinded and
>   deafened.
>
> If you desire, any spell you cast whose range is touch or greater can
>   originate from the projected image instead of from you. The projected
>   image can't cast any spells on itself except for illusion spells. The
>   spells affect other targets normally, despite originating from the
>   projected image.
>
> Objects are affected by the projected image as if they had succeeded
>   on their Will save. You must maintain line of effect to the projected
>   image at all times. If your line of effect is obstructed, the spell
>   ends. If you use dimension door, teleport, plane shift, or a similar
>   spell that breaks your line of effect, even momentarily, the spell
>   ends.

Once you know it is an illusion, you can :

- Cast ***dispel*** on it
- Obstruct the line of effect

**What would be the other methods to make this image disappear ?**
Can you for exemple, apply damage to it ?

Comment: Answerers - he knows line of effect would do it, he's not asking for ways to obstruct line of effect, he's asking for other ways than that to get rid of the image.

Answer (score 1):

An anti magic field could help. Apply the blind condition using [dirty tricks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Dirty-Trick), critical feats or class abilities, The barbarian might use his rage power [Spell Sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/spell-sunder-su/) . This allows him to dispel the image.

Comment: I don't think blinding breaks line of effect? Only line of sight.

Answer (score -1):

An image cannot take damage unless you create something new and add new rules for it.

Tossing chalk powder or flour at an area with an image will show that the image is not coated by the dust (unless the caster is nearby and can change the image quickly enough) to let everyone know that it is an image but that doesn't get rid of the image or the spell casting from it.  You can't affect the image itself without interfering with the magic that is creating it or, in this case, the line of effect with the caster.

So, the low tech solution is have someone with a tower shield run between the caster and the projected image.

Comment: I don't think the [tower shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/shield-tower/) would interfere: "As a standard action, however, you can use a tower shield to grant *you* total cover until the beginning of your next turn" (emphasis mine). Just because the tower shield's *wielder* has total cover doesn't create a line-of-sight-blocking obstacle between caster and *image.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan, it is the "even momentarily" wording in the spell description that led me to think of the tower shield (which is like a small, mobile, wall).